# How to use javascript method .after with multiple DIVs

Tags: javascript, css

I'm designing a web-based solution and I have multiple tables that vary in size (record lengths) from 1 to 25 or so rows.  I attempting to use the .after element by positioning the tables after the previous table, but I'm not sure how to implement.  That is, my first table is positioned with an absolute setting, but I assume the remaining tables should be set with relative positioning, but relative to what?

Below is my test code without absolute positioning of tables and it works fine.  But when I position the tables with absolute positioning, the insertadjacentHTML gets put at the top of the page.  Note that I'm coding in ASP and pulling from a database and the number of rows returned varies and I want to position each table below the previous table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<div id="table1">
<table border>
<tr>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="table2">
<table border>
<tr>
<td>table2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="table3">
<table border>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table3</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>



<script>
var h = document.getElementById("table3");
h.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<span style='color:red'>My span</span>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi dalezjc, looks like your code didn't make it into the post. Please edit it in.

Comment: Absolute positioning takes an element out of the normal flow, it doesn’t influence the position of any following elements any more - it’s basically as if the element wasn’t there at all in the first place. It is not even clear here _why_ you would chose to position that first table absolute here - so you need to do a better job with your description first of all. Explain what you want to achieve, and also show a [mre] that matches that (and not something else entirely, as you more or less did so far.)

Comment: I'm using the jQuery gauge widgets at the top of my page and the tables follow the gauges.  I'm using absolute positioning on the gauges as well.